# Error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable '$'

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Getting the following error when trying to compile with typescript 2.1:

> TypeScript error: node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3770,13): Error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable '$'.

Not sure what this means or how to fix.

Comment: If the error is at the point of requiring jquery - make sure you do it using `import * as $ from "jquery"`

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please can you ensure your question includes a small example of code that demonstrates the problem as you have supplied an error message but no code. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're likely importing and/or declaring JQuery multiple times and TypeScript is letting you know. Obviously, having duplicate declarations can lead to problems, especially if you're using plugins that attach themselves to the current `$` instance. If `$` is redeclared later, the plugins may no longer be available.

The correct thing to do would be to move all declarations into a single location, such as your index or main. However, if that's not possible, just tell TypeScript to ignore the duplicate declarations and carry on by adding the following property to your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Aren't modules scoped though? Why does TS consider importing a module a 're-declaration'? That seems wrong. Moving 'all imports' to one file is not a solution anyone would actually do. Also `skipLibCheck` does not fix this.

Comment: GN, the problem isn't redeclaring a module, it's redeclaring JQuery. That is, declaring the global variable `$` more than once. If multiple modules (or instances) declare the same global variable, TypeScript will let us know because they'll override each other. For example, JQuery can (and did) declare itself globally and not just within a module's scope. If the proposed solution of declaring globals in a single location isn't practical, another solution could be to check for JQuery (or any other global variable) in each module before importing/declaring it.