# How to import the same npm module in more than one TypeScript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, commonjs

### Question:

Whenever I import the same npm module in more than 1 TypeScript file, I got the error "`error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'os'`" as soon as I run the TypeScript compiler `tsc`.  My project setup is shown below.

I am using NodeJS v18.15.0.

---

### Setup:

Directory Structure

```
Project_Root
├─ main.ts
├─ worker.ts
├─ package.json
└─ tsconfig.json
```

main.ts

```
const worker = require('./worker');
const os = require('os');

console.log('name = ' + worker.getName() );
console.log('memory = ' + os.freemem() );
```

worker.ts

```
const os = require('os');

module.exports =
    class worker {
        static getName() : string { return "worker-" + os.freemem(); }
    }
```

package.json

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.15.11",
    "typescript": "^5.0.3"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": false
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

---

### Project Requirements:

- **Requirement #1**: No external packages (RequireJS/Babel/Webpack/etc), since disk space is limited.
- **Requirement #2**: IDE Intelli-sense should work. We can use any IDE.
- **Requirement #3**: We need to use the CommonJS-style "require" keyword for importing.

---

### What I have tried:

I have tried the top 3 answers in the following posts without success:

| Related Posts | Outcome |
| --- | --- |
| [Error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable '$'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41478596/error-ts2451-cannot-redeclare-block-scoped-variable) | Same error (after adding the "skipLibCheck: true" flag) |
| [How to solve this Cannot redeclare block scoped variable 'ngDevMode'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54037960/how-to-solve-this-cannot-redeclare-block-scoped-variable-ngdevmode) | Not Applicable (I am not using Angular) |
| [TS2451: Cannot Redeclare Block-scoped Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55108387/ts2451-cannot-redeclare-block-scoped-variable) | Not Applicable (I am not using ESLint) |
| [Getting build error in angular CLI: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51929360/getting-build-error-in-angular-cli-cannot-redeclare-block-scoped-variable-ngde) | Not Applicable (I am not using Angular) |
| [Import npm JS Module in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171980/import-npm-js-module-in-typescript) | Not Applicable (I am not using Electron) |

Comment: Does the error appear in the `const os = require('os')` line?

Comment: Hi @EldarB., yes. the error is from the "os" npm module.

Comment: I can replicate, made a brand new project had same unexpected error. I tried with both Typescript 5.0.3 and 4.9.5.

Comment: Have you tried `require('node:os')` that's how node docs suggest to import: https://nodejs.org/api/os.html

Comment: @JBallin not the OP but I tried that, doesn't fix and shouldn't be needed depending on which version of node we're talking about (I tried both 16 and 18).

Comment: Hi @JaredSmith, I received the same error when I tried `require('node:os')`.

Comment: "Also, the other post is 8 years old, with the top answer no longer working in 2023"—age alone is not a reason to post a new question. If the other post _is_ a duplicate (I'm not sure), make sure to look at _all_ answers. You can vote up good, more recent answers. You can also post a bounty if you want new answers. "This is why the StackOverFlow's Similar-Question Checker didn't bring up that post when I created this question"—no, Stack Overflow's similar question "checker" didn't bring up that post because the similar question logic is awful. It very rarely finds actual duplicates on its own.

Comment: @Chris The accepted answer in the dupe is almost identical to the accepted answer here and is 4 months old.

Comment: Hi @Chris, would you please take review the following difference? Thanks.  -  Difference: The other post deals with declarations in "unrelated" files. This posts deals with declarations that are used in related files that will be used together during runtime.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. The problem is the same. The files are transpiled together and they share the scope. The accepted solution is identical. It makes no difference whether the files are related or unrelated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because TypeScript doesn't consider the two files modules, and makes them share their scope. You can use the `moduleDetection` field in tsconfig to force them to be recognized as modules:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleDetection": "force"
  }
}
```

[There's a discussion about this on the TS GitHub Repo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47229)